# How to specify intervals between labels on category axis (x-axis) of line chart?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm modeling time series data that spans a year on a line chart. I have the category-axis labels as dates, but it is automatically showing 12 labels (dates) on the x-axis. I would like to change this to showing 3 or 4 labels.

On powerpoint itself, this feature would be under Format Axis --> Axis Options --> Labels --> then changing "Interval between labels" from automatic to 'specify interval unit'. I don't know how to do this within the code.

Additionally, it would be helpful to know how to set a category axis as a date axis.

```
def add_stock_chart(ppt,data, company, slide_num =0):
    # data is a series indexed by date -- dates are all written as 'Excel numbers'
    # company_name is a string of the company's ticker

    slide = ppt.slides[slide_num]

    chart_data = CategoryChartData()

    chart_data.categories = data.index.tolist()
    chart_data.add_series(str(company),tuple(data.values.tolist()))





    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(.403), Inches(5.33), Inches(2.22), Inches(1.3)
    chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
        XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
    ).chart

    chart.font.size = Pt(8)
    chart.font.name = 'Arial'

    date_axis = chart.category_axis
    date_axis.tick_labels.number_format = 'mmm-yy'
    date_axis.major_unit = 90
    chart.has_legend = False
    chart.show_legend_key = False

    chart.has_title = False
    chart.series[0].smooth = True

    return ppt
```

Comment: you should post at least a bit of code, the packages you are using, or the expected and current outputs for us to understand the problem.

Comment: Added, sorry about that.

Comment: When `chart_data.categories` are Python date or datetime objects, the chart gets a date axis.